# Java: casting primitive wrappers classes

Tags: java, casting, strong-typing

I have following method that I use when traversing values in JSON document:

```java
protected static <T> T getValueAs(Object untypedValue, Class<T> expectedType) {
    if (expectedType.isAssignableFrom(untypedValue.getClass())) {
        return (T) untypedValue;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed");
}
```

In most of the cases it works just fine, but it fails (throws exception) when called like:

```java
getValueAs((Long) 1L, Double.class);
```

I know that this is due to incompatibility of `Long` and `Double`:

`Double d = (Long) 1L;` results in `error: incompatible types: Long cannot be converted to Double`.

I wonder if somehow I can make my method work even in such case - `Long` value gets converted into `Double`?

I have seen [isAssignable() from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#isAssignable-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-boolean-) but I think it will only make condition work pass and things will fail on casting - I have expected type `Double` and value is of type `Long` (not primitives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this overloaded method be acceptable?

```
Double n = getValueAs(1L, Number.class, Number::doubleValue);

protected static <P,T> T getValueAs(Object untypedValue, Class<P> expectedType, Function<P, T> f) {
    if (expectedType.isAssignableFrom(untypedValue.getClass())) {
        return f.apply((P)untypedValue);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed");
}
```

Comment: Actually this is almost exactly what I have arrived at independently - I'm just calling `getValueAs(1L, Number.class).doubleValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have no choice but to perform a conversion. But since your method won't know how to convert values of unknown classes, you can leave that as the responsibility of the caller:

```
protected static <T> T getValueAs(Object untypedValue, Class<T> expectedType) {
    return getValueAs(untypedValue, expectedType, null);
}

protected static <T> T getValueAs(Object untypedValue, Class<T> expectedType, 
                                  Function<Object, T> converter) {
    if (expectedType.isAssignableFrom(untypedValue.getClass())) {

        //use Class.cast to skip unchecked cast warning
        return expectedType.cast(untypedValue); 
    } else if (null != converter) {
        return converter.apply(untypedValue);
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Failed");
}
```

And the invocation may be something like this:

```
getValueAs(1L, Double.class, v -> ((Number) v).doubleValue());
```

Of course, you can add to `getValueAs()` a few conversions that your method supports, particularly for the most common scenarios; so your callers don't have to write converters for those.

Comment: I think in the first method you forgot to add a null as 3rd parameter.

Comment: Thx @ernest_k for good hint with `Number` and `doubleValue`!